# git add/commit deleting and not just ignoring .gitignore ignored file

Tags: git, github, gitignore

i've tried what was suggested by a previous Stackoverflow question about how to ignore files: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

what was suggested:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

the command I'm using:

```
git rm -r --cached application/config/config.php
//i only want to ignore this one file
```

Unfortunately, when I do `git add.` and then `git commit` my config.php is **deleted** from the repository and not just ignored.

I have a .gitignore file in my root directory and it contains the following list item:

```
application/config/config.php
```

might someone be able to help me understand why this config.php file is being **deleted** and just not being ignored?

here's what my git status shows:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#   modified:   application/config/config.php
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

thank you,

tim

Comment: what is the `git status` report before you do the `add .` and `commit`?

Comment: hi Ali, please see modified question above, thanks!

Comment: You've modified the file. Try `git checkout -- application/config/config.php`

Comment: hi mschonaker, thanks for your input, the answer below about using `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>` is what worked for me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's being removed from the repository because you removed it. `git rm` is to remove the file and the `--cached` keeps it in your working directory.

You can do `git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>` if you want to make it so it just never notices changes to a file, but leaves the old version in your repository. Further reading here: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html

Comment: Hi Dan, that worked perfectly! I had a suspicion that `rm` wasn't the right command but didn't know about `git update-index...`. thanks!